# convert IList<Derived> to IReadOnlyCollection<Base>

Tags: c#, collections

I have a private field `IList<DerivedClass> _elements` and want to create a property returning `IReadOnlyCollection<BaseClass>`.

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<BaseClass> BaseClasses
{
    get { return _elements; } // compile time error
}
```

How to do that without running into compile errors?

(afaik this should work, as the `T` in `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is covariant)

Comment: What exactly is the compile time error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`List<T>.AsReadOnly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) method:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<BaseClass> BaseClasses
{
    get { return _elements.Cast<BaseClass>().ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
}
```

Or since `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is covariant you can skip `Cast<BaseClass>`:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<BaseClass> BaseClasses
{
    get { return _elements.ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
}
```

You could even skip `ToList()` if your field was `List<T>`, not `IList<T>`.

Comment: Thank you. One last tiny additional question: it looks like I could skip `AsReadOnly()` as well. Is it bad practice to skip it? I guess a potential API user could then evil-cast it back to non-read-only...

Comment: You can't skip `AsReadOnly` because `IList<T>` does not implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: I switched to List<T> instead of IList<T> to save ToList(). List does seem to implement IReadOnlyCollection<T> as well.